# Changing the default "Allow items from this list to appear in search results?" to No when a list is provisioned

Tags: list, crawling

How can I change the default setting on "Allow items from this list to appear in search results?" in SharePoint 2007 to be "No" when a list is created?

No every list created needs crawled so I'd like to flip the switch to "No" as a default.

Bismarck

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the default value out of the box, it will be set to yes.

An option is to create an [SPListEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440468.aspx) to listen when a list is created, and set the value to no (ListAdding/ListAdded event handlers).

Depending on your requirements another option may be to create several list templates that can have the value set to no.

Answer (score -1):

You could always create a site, set it up exactly the way you'd like it to be, then save that site as a template. Then use that template to create your sites going forward.

Comment: Setting a site template up will still have a newly created list set to yes.